# InfoWindow for Google Maps should expand width as necessary but have a vertical scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I am using `infowindows` on a google map but I would like the width of the `infowindow` to expand as much as needed but for there to be a vertical scrollbar when the window is at a certain height.

I set the div class around the content of the `infowindow` to have the following:

```
.mapInfoWindow {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto; 
}
```

But this seems to somehow limit the width as well due to the now present vertical scrollbar.

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Zm8w/155/). I would like, for example, the address to take up as much space as it needs.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your issue? It's pretty specific and a working sample might shed some light

Comment: Try consider creating a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it'll be useful for you and other SO users also.

Comment: Better if you could create a similar [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Comment: See the update to the question with a link to the fiddle.